# New harddrive is giving fatal I/O errors, is it something I did?

Tags: hard-drive

I just bought a new HDD from seagate this week. It's an 8tb ironwolf drive. I'm downloading torrentpacks of old abandonware mame games and things like that and I keep getting Error messages about device I/O errors and things like that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsqJc.jpg

I bought the drive because the old WD Green (about a year old) started doing the same thing, so I wanted to buy a new drive and copy data from one to another and send the WD back in for replacement.

I did copy about 3.5TB worth of data from the WD onto the new seagate drive, I used a tool called "Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier" to prevent copying anything with bad sectors, it skipped a ton of files that were either corrupt or missing pieces.

**To the point**

What are the chances that this new drive came with issues? The only test I ran on it before starting massive file copies was a smart test... it passed that, and still passes it. I downloaded seagates drive tools and the drive seems fails on the Long/Short generic tests....
Here are the results of all the tests in the seagate software..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f3QF.jpg

- Do I have a bad drive?
- If so, is there a way to fix it without loosing data?
- Is there a way to fix it with loosing data?
- After "fixing" it, how can I be sure that the issue is truly gone before putting more data on the drive.
- Copying from a bad drive to a good drive couldn't cause this right?
- If I end up getting a new drive, what should be the FIRST thing I do next time?

I appreciate any help.

*System Specs*
https://pcpartpicker.com/list/pQppRG

Comment: are you using the same cable?

Comment: Nope, different sata cable, different sata port on mobo

Comment: yeah, its useful to rule both those things out

Comment: Yea, I tried two different sata ports with two different cables that was my first thought.

Comment: I always perform a 24 hour burn-in on new HDDs, usually just performing the (internal) SMART long tests.  Idea is to detect a bad drive or induce infantile failure.  You can (still) run the SMART test(s), which are read-only tests.